# Program will not run properly as scheduled task. Manually executing the program runs fine

Tags: c#, .net, scheduled-tasks, exchange-server

I have been trying to convert this one program to run as a scheduled task. The program runs fine whenever I manually run it, but it does not seem to run properly as a scheduled task. The task scheduler will say it is running and completes successfully, but nothing is logged nor results are outputted to files. When run manually, I get the results I want.

I am using visual studio 2015 with .NET version 4.6.2 on the server. I have tried compiling the program for all different versions of .NET but no luck.

The file is located in the local drive and executed from C:\folder\folder\bin\debug\executable(application). The files that it is suppose to write are also located in the debug folder. I do not specify the full path of the files to be written to cause I assume since the files are in the working directory, it will locate the specified files.

Any help would be much appreciated. I've been looking at this for too long.

Thanks

Comment: Which user are you running the task under?

Comment: Also know that there's no way anyone can say "You need to do X" here, there could be many reasons why your program doesn't run properly when scheduled so most likely this question will get closed as Too Broad.

Comment: Also, *please don't assume*. When you set up a scheduled task you have the option to specify "Start in", did you do that?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen see that is the kind of answer i need. I think it is working now. Why does "Start in" make such a big difference? If the path is specified wouldn't it use that directory?

Comment: Programs start running in their current working directory. It doesn't matter if you specify the path on the command line. There are good reasons for that. For example, the program's executable is often (probably should be) in a directory that users can't write to. If the program specifies output files in the default directory, changing to the program file's location would cause output to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
this.Focus();
this.BringToFront();
```

at `form_Load` of Your starting form.